routing slip in Kafka (call topics in order)
Imagine I have a chronograph system, which order is important for me. for example I have a producer which push a data to first topic in Kafka using Confluent.Kafka in c#.
Then I have a consumer which listens to the first topic, after every thing is correct I call 2nd topic, well I have a validation to choose the next destination, would my first condition true call  3rd topic otherwise call 4th. and also I need compensation for each call, if third has problem rollback and back to the 2nd back to the 1st. is any best practice for this approach? I know routing slip with Masstransit, give us this ability, using activities; however, I have no Idea if it is possible to use it in Kafa, or any alternative, otherwise I have to implement something manually.

Routing slips only work with brokers, not riders like Kafka.

Kafka is broker too! Am I wrong?

Kafka is a log file with an API. I cover some differences in this video.
